# Windows flickering

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi

I have been delving into the guts of Win32 (Windows 7 on my machine), trying to combat the flicker that occurs when you are resizing or maximising a window. Basically when you resize a window win32 "helps" by blitting the current window contents to the top left of the new client area. Of course, this is now rarely what is wanted, the correct resized version follows quickly after, but the flickering blit is still annoying, especially since WPF has nicely solved a lot of flickering issues for other scenarios. The second is when rezing a window manually you often get black strips or bars around the right and bottom edges, as well as controls jiggling. This appears to be that WPF layout manager can't keep up with DirectX.

As solutions I have tried:

Intercepting WM_NCCALCSIZE - after a few hours tinkering, doesn't seem to do any good.
Trying different window styles - WS_POPUP, WS_BORDER, WS_OVERLAPPED etc.
Intercepting maximise minimize an sizing, and manually resizing with SetWindowPos.
Using SetWindowPos with the SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_DEFERERASE.
Sending WM_SETDRAW FALSE before the window is moved.

Nothing seems to work - is the blitting a core and uncontrollable internal of HWND? Maybe I could delve into directx, or reverse engineer User32.dll and patch it. (just semi-joking about the latter)

Best Regards,
Steve

Comment: To completely eliminate flicker is impossible but you can vastly improve it by making redraw-on-resize an "atomic" operation. By that I mean, all the new control sizes should be set using the `SWP_NOREDRAW` flag to prevent them redrawing as you resize them. Then use `WM_PRINTCLIENT` to draw the new window to an off-screen bitmap. Finally, blit to the display. It's much harder than it sounds to get it working unfortunately but that's the best approach I've found.

Comment: Not sure if this is a case here, but returning TRUE from WM_ERASEBKGND, eliminates background drawing.